# Promise.jsm demo of Promise.all and Promise.defer

Tags: javascript, promise

I created this demo example for [MDN documentation to show how to use `Promise.all` and `Promise.defer` in user created promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm#Make_user_defined_promise_return_after_multiple_images_finish_loading_%28Promise.all_and_Promise.defer%29). I used `let`s because I thought if I didn't it would mess it up.

People are recommending I avoid `let` because the standard is not there yet and it looks like when it lands it will be a little different.  Can you please advise?

The code downloads images from an array and after all images are downloaded it completes the main `promise`.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm");

var myPromise = myUserDefinedPromise();
myPromise.then(
  function(aSuccessReason) {
    alert('myPromise was SUCCESFUL and reason was = "' + aSuccessReason + '"');
  },
  function(aRejectReason) {
    alert('myPromise FAILED for reason = "' + uneval(aRejectReason) + '"');
  }
);

function myUserDefinedPromise() {
  try {
    var mySubPromises = [];

    var imagePaths = ['http://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/favicon.png', 'https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/favicon32.png'];
    [].forEach.call(imagePaths, function(path) {
      let myImage = new Image();
      let loadThisImagePromise = Promise.defer();
      mySubPromises.push(loadThisImagePromise.promise);
      myImage.onload = function() {
        loadThisImagePromise.resolve('Succesfully loaded image at path = "' + path + '" the width of this image is = "' + this.naturalWidth + '".');
        if (!this.naturalWidth) {
          loadThisImagePromise.reject('Image loaded but it has 0 width at path = "' + path + '" the naturalWidth was 0');
        }
      }
      myImage.onerror = function(e) {
        loadThisImagePromise.reject('An error occured while loading path = "' + path + '". The error = ' + uneval(e));
      }
      myImage.onabort = function(e) {
        loadThisImagePromise.reject('Image load was aborted loading path = "' + path + '".');
      }
      myImage.src = path;
    });

    return Promise.all(mySubPromises);
  } catch(ex) {
    return Promise.reject(ex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding `var` vs. `let`

> People are recommending I avoid let because the standard is not there yet and it looks like when it lands it will be a little different. Can you please advise?

Regarding your comment: "People"'s opinion on `var` vs. `let` is a *bit* off... It makes sense for the web not to use `let` just yet as not all browsers support `let`.

But within the mozilla code base let is actually already used since years and pretty stable. There are more than 83.000 `let`s in mozilla-central (via `ag -w let | wc -l`). Brendan Eich (I think) coined the term "let is the new var" (for mozilla-specific code) way back when JS1.7 was released a part of Firefox 2 in 2006. Ever since, it has seen wide-spread adoption within the mozilla code base and add-ons alike.

**But**, since you're writing documentation, it would be better to follow the lead of the main MDN contributors, even if you write mozilla-specific examples aimed at platform and add-on developers. I'm not sure what the MDN policy is on this...
I wrote a bunch of mozilla-specific examples in the past for MDN, and used `let` and other stuff like generators, and never was told to stop that. But maybe I just wasn't *caught*.

#### Replacing one with the other

You asked about this [in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56824/28865), but I think it would be more appropriate to answer here.

In general you can replace `var` with `let` in most cases, except where you really want the hoisting rules. E.g. one example where stuff would break.

```
try {
  var name = getName();
} catch (ex) { ... }
console.log(name);
```

But with `let`, `name` will be only valid within the try-block.

```
try {
  let name = getName();
} catch (ex) { ... }
console.log(name); // Either undefined or an error, depending on strict-mode.
```

You could still write this as (and I guess it would have been a good idea to write it like this in the first place, even with `var`).

```
let name;
try {
  name = getName();
} catch (ex) { ... }
console.log(name); // Either undefined or an error, depending on strict-mode.
```

The other way round is more tricky. Don't do it blindly. Be aware of name clashes it may create due to different scoping/hoisting rules, and what scoping difference means for "global" code in particular.

A problematic example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  let p = i * 10;
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(p) });
}
// 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90
```

Using `var p` is wildly different because `p` gets hoisted outside of the loop block while `let p` is hoisted within the block (JS1.7) or not-really-hoisted-but-kinda (ES6):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  var p = i * 10;
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(p) });
}
// 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90
```

#### JS1.7 to ES6 differences.

The hoisting difference of `let` is the most important practical difference between JS1.7 and ES6 `let`.

```
(function() { console.log(i); let i = 0; })();
```

This will log `undefined` in JS1.7, but should throw an error in ES6 because `i` was referenced before it actually was declared.

Since you should avoid to write such code anyway, it shouldn't really make much difference in practice, except to expose the occasional bug once the engine switches from JS1.7 to ES6 behavior.

There are some other differences (e.g. no more let-blocks), but I'd consider them extremely minor in practice and don't think these differences would affect lots of production code.

### Regarding `Promise.jsm` documentation and your code.

Well, I don't really think the example is appropriate:

1. It relies on the network.
2. It relies on some external resources, which may get removed in the future at any point.
3. It isn't simple enough.
4. It is incorrect when put into a strict-mode function.

If write an example like this, keeping it as simple as possible.

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm');

/**
 * Example function, just returning a promise that
 * will resolve or reject after a timeout.
 */
function createTimeoutPromise(shouldSucceed, timeout) {
  var p = Promise.defer();
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (shouldSucceed) {
      p.resolve(timeout);
    } 
    else {
      p.reject(timeout);
    }
  }, timeout);
  return p.promise;
}

/**
 * Success case.
 */
(function() {
  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    promises.push(createTimeoutPromise(true, i * 100));
  }
  var combined = Promise.all(promises);
  combined.then(
    function onResolved(result) {
      console.log('resolved', result);
    },
    function onRejected(result) {
      console.log('rejected', result);
    });
  // Since all promises eventually resolve/succeed, onResolved will be called.
  // Promise.all will pass an array of all resolve() results.
  // This hence logs:
  // "resolved" Array [ 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900 ]
})();

/**
 * Failure case.
 */
(function() {
  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // Odd numbered promises should fail: i % 2 == 0
    promises.push(createTimeoutPromise(i % 2 == 0, i * 100));
  }
  var combined = Promise.all(promises);
  combined.then(
    function onResolved(result) {
      console.log('resolved', result);
    },
    function onRejected(result) {
      console.log('rejected', result);
    });
  // Since odd numbered promises will be rejected/fail, onRejected will be called.
  // Promise.all will immediately reject the returned combined promise once the
  // first sub-promise fails, i.e. promise "100".
  // Other resolved and rejected promises won't be passed.
  // This hence logs
  // "rejected" 100
})();
```

I'm not quite sure how much of a point there is maintaining `Promise.jsm` documentation, since ES6 `Promise`s landed in the meantime. I'd expect that `Promise.jsm` will get phased out at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my implementation:

```
// So we define a function that loads images, and returns a promise for us to listen to
function loadImages(images){

  // We can take advantage of `map` which iterates through an array and makes an array
  // out of the returns of each iteration. In this case, we return a promise for each
  // url, for `Promise.all` to listen to later.
  var promises = images.map(function(url){

    // Create a Deferred object and image, and handle the resolution stuff.
    var deferred = Promise.defer();
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){deferred.resolve('image success: '+ url);};
    image.onerror = function(){deferred.reject('image failed: ' + url);};
    image.onerror = function(){deferred.reject('image aborted: ' + url);};
    image.src = url;

    // Return the promise, which will be stored in the array, thanks to `map`
    return deferred;
  });

  // Listen on the array of promises (aha moment: jQuery.when == Promises.all, more or less.)
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

// Now we use `loadImages`, loading an array of urls, and listening for notices
loadImages([
  'http://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/favicon.png',
  'https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/favicon32.png'
]).then(function(value){
  console.log('loadImages successful: ' + value);
},function(error){
  console.log('loadImages failed: ' + error);
});
```

**Additional notes:**

- Don't do `[].forEach.call`. Aside from looking very hackish, it creates an unnecessary array. Do `Array.prototype.forEach.call` instead.
- I'd avoid using `try-catch`. While it's a good measure for errors, it's bad for optimization. Some optimizing compilers (I think V8) can't optimize code inside `try-catch`.
- Name your variables and functions properly and verbosely.

Comment: Oh my gosh so simple and sweet. I had to make some corrections. Please see here: [GitHubGist :: Revisions](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ae0da26d6863b389bde9/revisions). And lastly you see that I added a commented out line `alert(blah)`, if you uncomment this, how can you make it trigger the `error` function of the `loadImages` `promise` without a `try-catch`? Please see my comments here for more explanation on the revisions: [GitHubGist :: Comments on Revisions](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ae0da26d6863b389bde9#comment-1262513)

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments within the code, especially that aha moment on `jQuery.when` :) I also just learned the `map` function I never understood it. Thanks!

Comment: @Noitidart Ahh, sorry about the mistakes. I used promises before I decided to use `Promise.defer`. Hehehe.

Comment: @Noitidart Regarding the `alert`, I don't know. I think the only way to trigger the fail function is to reject the promise.